# How use Lookup MongoDB in F#

Tags: c#, f#

I have the following in C#

```cs
var pipe = collection
                .Aggregate()
                .Match(filter)
                .Lookup("entity", "localField", "foreignField", "as");
```

This works thanks to the implicit conversion, but F# does not support implicit conversion. How implement the above in F#?

How to perform the explicit conversion from string to FieldDefinition?

```fs
let pipe = collection.Aggregate().Match(filter).Lookup("", "", "", "")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could invoke `FieldDefinition<_>.op_Implicit(fieldName)` manually if you want, but the MongoDB driver actually has a class called `StringFieldDefinition` that's slightly easier:

```
let pipe =
    let localField = StringFieldDefinition<_>("localField")
    let foreignField = StringFieldDefinition<_>("foreignField")
    let as' = StringFieldDefinition<_>("as")
    collection
        .Aggregate()
        .Match(fun _ -> true)
        .Lookup("entity", localField, foreignField, as')
```